# How do you turn off the loud bing sound effect when checking off a task on Microsoft ToDo?

Tags: microsoft-to-do

How do you turn off the loud bing sound effect when checking off a task on Microsoft ToDo?

I've looked on answers.microsoft.com but they don't have any answer on how to do it

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/mute-microsoft-to-do-sounds/8189e4c0-35e2-4559-bd8d-e56b2e1bf33c

I don't normally use the program but a just having a look at it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting here

Disable "Play Completion Sound"

[image]